# ui-router Inherited Resolved Dependencies

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, promise

I was trying to implement a secure area with an abstract state that is then implemented by concrete states.

According to [this blog post](http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Dependencies_inheritance_using_ui-router/), I thought i could have the abstract state resolve the authentication and have the concrete states rely on it, because as stated in ui-router docs

> Child states will inherit resolved dependencies from parent state(s)

But later on, the same ui-router doc mentions that

> The resolve keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the children.

and indeed, if i comment out the `resolve`line on the concrete state, it doesnt work anymore.

So i am really missing something. **If ChildState inherit resolved dependencies, why should they be re-injected?**

my code below :

```
router.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    var authentication = ["Auth", function(Auth) {

                    return Auth.$requireAuth();
                }];

    .state('secure', {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<navbar></navbar><ui-view/>',
            resolve: authentication


        })

        .state('secure.concrete', {
            url: '/concrete',
            templateUrl: 'views/concrete.html',
            controller: 'concreteCtrl',
            resolve: authentication  // <--- if i comment this out, it wont work
        })
```

**UPDATE :**

After hours of tears, it looks like i'm going the wrong path. The problem doesnt come from inherited resolved dependencies, but from the fact that once the promisse is resolved, it's not "resetted".

**Is there anyway to force the promise to be re-setted / re-evaluated on each state change ?**

Comment: Why should what be re-what with the what? Re-evaluated on each state change of what?

Comment: i guess this means my question wasnt understandable, i apologize for that, but if you'll certainly understand that your comment is unreplyable. If you want to help me further, you are welcome, but please elaborate on what is not clear...

Comment: Nice! I added an equally obfuscated comment, apparently. Sorry for that. I think the main points I'm confused on are the meat of the question (e.g. `"If ChildState inherit resolved dependencies, why should they be re-injected?"` and `"Is there anyway to force the promise to be re-setted / re-evaluated on each state change?"`). Are we talking about expired tokens or calling `unauth()` and then the promise is not re-evaluated? Does [this look like it may help](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/components/security/security.js#L59)? If so I can elaborate.

Comment: OMG that's exactly it! thx for the link! i need to study it a bit deeper! for the moment, i solve the issue by having the {reload: true} option set for any state change. But i'd really like to understand the ground concept. i leave ticket open, and any of your comment will be appreciated!

Comment: by state change, i mean ui-router's $state changes (e.g. $state.go()...)

Answer (score 2):

The problems may result from incorrect `resolve` syntax, it should be an object:

```
resolve: {
  authentication: authentication
}
```

'MUST be injected into the child states' means that `authentication` should be explicitly stated as child state controller dependency. Duplicate `resolve` on child state isn't an injection; it will just make `authentication` called twice.

Comment: changing the `resolve` synttax using an object didnt help. Same result.

Comment: but it make me think that i dont inject the promise in any controller... The promise eventually fires a ChangeStateError event, caught by $rootScope.$on, that then event.preventDefault() and redirect $state.go().

Comment: do you think the promise should be injected in a controller?

Comment: @Developpeurtunisie Yes, it should be injected into controller, for example. `authentication` can also be injected to other state parts (child's `templateProvider` or own resolvers), that's what cited manual excerpt refers to when it says 'be injected into the child states' and not just 'into a child's controller'.

Comment: So it should be injected into every concrete state's controller "extending" the abstract one?

Comment: @Developpeurtunisie  The necessity to do this may depend on how view hierarchy is built (may be not required if child view can't be rendered without parent), but yes, the rule of thumb is to inject it into child controller. I think that [this example](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies) matches the question pretty closely.

Comment: I think the problem come from the fact that once the promisse has been resolved, it's not "resetted". I updated my question accordingly...

Comment: @Developpeurtunisie If Auth.$requireAuth() returns a new promise on each call, the resolver returns a new promise on each state change also.

Comment: Auth.$requireAuth is, according to angularFire doc's, a  `Helper method which returns a promise fulfilled with the current authentication state if the user is authenticated but otherwise rejects the promise.`, so yes

Comment: instead of calling state.go() or ui-sref normally, i call them with state.go(state, {reload:true}) or <a ui-sref="state" ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}"> and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick for me but i'm not exactly sure why :

instead of calling state.go() or ui-sref normally, i call them with state.go(state, {reload:true}) or

that way the resolve seems to be re-evaluated.